# Scala function takes 2 hours with 2 million values

Tags: list, scala

Would be grateful if any ideas to speed it up!

```
  case class Pair(aa:String, bb:String)
  case class OutputRow(bb:String, aa:String, bb_2:String, aa_2:String)

  def startSearch(
            _1_sorted: Array[Pair] ,
            _2_hashmap: HashMap[String, String] ) : ArrayBuffer[OutputRow] = {

    var outputTableListBuffer = ArrayBuffer[OutputRow]()
    var searchComparisionFlag = false

    var storeMain = Pair("0","0") //Initialize with Dummy data

    var i = 0
    def search(xxxx_1: Pair): Unit = {

      if (searchComparisionFlag==true) {
        var _2_exists = _2_hashmap.exists(_._1 == xxxx_1.aa)
        if (_2_exists) {
          val _2_xxxx = _2_hashmap(xxxx_1.aa)
          outputTableListBuffer.append(OutputRow(storeMain.aa, storeMain.bb,_2_xxxx, xxxx_1.aa))
          i = i + 1
          if (i % 1000 == 0) println("In recursive search storeMain: ", storeMain)
          var storePair = Pair(_2_xxxx,xxxx_1.aa)
          search(storePair)
        } else {
          searchComparisionFlag = false
          return
        }
      } else {
        var _2_exists = _2_hashmap.exists(_._1 == xxxx_1.aa)

        if (_2_exists) {
          val _2_xxxx = _2_hashmap(xxxx_1.aa)
          searchComparisionFlag = true
          outputTableListBuffer.append(OutputRow(xxxx_1.aa, xxxx_1.bb,_2_xxxx, xxxx_1.aa))
          var store = Pair(_2_xxxx,xxxx_1.aa)
          search(store)
        }
      }
    }

    _1_sorted.foreach{ aa_1 =>
      val store = Pair(aa_1.aa, aa_1.bb)
      storeMain = store
      search(store)
    }
    outputTableListBuffer
  }
```

The above function takes 2 hours with 1 million values in _1_sorted and with a good 1 Million lookup in the hashmap.

Any ideas to speed this up?

This is a recursive logic function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is this:

```
_2_hashmap.exists(_._1 == xxxx_1.aa)
```

This is checking every single element of the hashmap on every call. Instead, use `get`:

```
_2_hashmap.get(xxxx_1.aa) match {
  Some(_2_xxxx) => // Found
    ???
  None => // Not found
    ???
}
```

Other code issues:

- Don't use `return`
- Pass flags down through recursive call rather than using global `var`
- Use `val` wherever possible
- Don't start variable names with `_`